# how to restrict special characters in IOS programming

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a urlstring that I use to for a web request and it contains the value %20C and for some reason that converts it to a Chinese character. It is a different Chinese character every time  which doesn't really make any sense to me. All i want is for it not to be converted to the Chinese Character. How do I restrict that?
Thanks in advance.

```
NSString * name=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"username"];
NSString * name_new = [name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/trans.php?id1=%@&id2=%@&num=%i",nums[z], name_new, nums2[z]];
NSLog(urlString);
```

Comment: `%20` is the space character so `%20C` is really `" C"`.

Comment: Please show your real code.

Comment: That is what I want to happen but it outputs as 뺰

Comment: What kind of values are in your `nums` and `nums2` arrays? Perhaps using `%@` isn't proper for `nuns[z]` since you are using `%i` for `nums2[z]`.

Comment: nums[] is an array of formatted NSStrings and nums2[] is an array of integers

Comment: Try changing your log to: `NSLog(@"URL = %@", urlString);`.

Comment: The 1st argument to `NSLog` should always be a format string, not just a string variable.